Как написать функцию, которая возвращает средний возраст пользователей одного пола?
Не могу решить задачу. Нужно создать функцию getUsersNamesInAgeRange(users, gender), которая возвращает среднее значение возраста пользователей одного пола.
На данный момент смогла написать только так, но результат неверный:
function getUsersNamesInAgeRange(users, gender) {
    const filteredGender = users.filter((user) => {
        return user.gender === gender;
    });
    const ageSum = users.reduce((sum, user) => {
    return sum + user.age
}, 0);

  return ageSum / users.length
}

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

У вас была проблема в том, что вы после фильтрации users всё равно использовали его же, вместо отфильтрованного filteredGender
function getUsersNamesInAgeRange(users, gender) {

    const filteredGender = users.filter((user) => user.gender === gender);
    if (filteredGender.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    const ageSum = filteredGender.reduce((sum, user) => sum + user.age, 0);
    return ageSum / filteredGender.length;
}


Спасибо огромное, добрый человек! А я уже второй день ломаю голову в этой задачей

@Belka_zub, если мой ответ помог вам, пожалуйста, отметьте его решением. Буду благодарен

да, отметила)) спасибо))


Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Например не стоит делать два прохода по данным... Ну и за переменными следить. ;)


const users = [
  {age: 20, gender: 0}, 
  {age: 30, gender: 1}, 
  {age: 40, gender: 0}, 
  {age: 10, gender: 1}, 
]
const gender = 1
console.log(getUsersNamesInAgeRange(users, gender))

//
function getUsersNamesInAgeRange(users, gender) {
  const o = users.reduce((o, u) => {
    if (u.gender === gender) {
      o.count++
      o.sum += u.age
    }
    return o
  }, {count: 0, sum: 0});
  return o.count ? o.sum / o.count : null
}






const users = [
  {age: 20, gender: 0}, 
  {age: 30, gender: 1}, 
  {age: 40, gender: 0}, 
  {age: 10, gender: 1}, 
]

console.log(
   users
     // Сначала фильтруем нужный гендер
     .filter(val => val.gender == 1)
     // Потом можно сразу посчитать среднее арифметическое 
     // за один проход
     .reduce(
       (avg,val,idx) => avg + (val.age - avg)/(idx + 1),
        0
      )
   );



